# 2560 x 1440 on a Dell Latitude E4300?

Tags: display, resolution, dell-latitude

Does anyone know if a new Dell Latitude E4300 (which has a Intel®  Graphics Media Accelerator 4500MHD) can run 2560x1440 screen resolution?

The computer has 4GB ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-integrated-graphics/

Yes it supports it in every way of output according to the sheet. (Also I read on my T500 manual book that it supports it with both VGA.)

(By the way nice machine, like the design. Maybe I'll look around at Dell when my ThinkPad dies. It looks really nice. :))

Comment: Btw, will the VGA port on the E4300 support that resolution?

Comment: Yes the paper said even VGA port supports it. (Check the link thoroughly, VGA is at the end of the listing.)